# How to call ManagedScheduledExecutorService for every 1 mins for 10 mins only not indefinitely

Tags: java

I want to use `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` - `scheduleAtFixedRate` to trigger a task which need to be run every 1 mins for 10 mins only but with `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` I don't have a way to do that. It takes as param the task, the initial delay, period and time unit only and runs indefinitely.

Example code:

```
class TestDisplayMessage {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler
        = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestDisplayMessage testDisplayMessage = new TestDisplayMessage();
        testDisplayMessage.displayMessage();

   }


   public void displayMessage() {
       final Runnable display = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               System.out.println("scheduleAtFixedRate");
           }
       };

       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(display, 1, 1, MINUTES);
   }
}
```

I want to display the message only 10 times i.e after the initial delay of 1 min the task will run then after every 1 mins(period param) it will display the message and goes on. I want it to display only 10 times i.e for 10 mins only that is the task need to be run for a specific period of time in my case 10 mins only and not indefinitely.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code and show what you've tried

Comment: @Micho . Thanks for your help. I posted my code. Can you please have a look and advise

Comment: One option is to use a self-scheduling task, like the `FollowupTask` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775822/3080094)